# Double space not being preserved in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm using the lowagie.text.pdf library to create a PDF document from within my java application, however I have realised that strings with double spacing in them i.e. "DOUBLE  SPACE" aren't preserved.Is this a .PDF limitation or have I overlooked something else ?

```
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
float[] columnWidths = new float[columnCount];

PdfPCell headerCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(gridColumn.getCaption(), font));

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(0.5f);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
table.setHeaderRows(1);

for (PdfPCell headerCell : headerCells) {
    table.addCell(headerCell);
}

String value = "DOUBLE  SPACED";

table.addCell(new Phrase(value, font));

Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, pdfStream);
pdfDocument.addTitle(caption);
pdfDocument.open();
pdfDocument.add(table);
pdfDocument.close();'
```

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Show us your code. 2. I need to say that `com.lowagie` (up to 2.1.7) is obsolete, you should use `com.itextpdf` (5.0.0 and up - currently 5.5.8, 5.5.9 will be released in March).

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Formatting is messed up in comments.

Comment: Hi Amedee, I have refactored it slightly ! But I hope the above will give you a vague idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have realised that strings with double spacing in them i.e. "DOUBLE  SPACE" aren't preserved

That depends on what you mean by being *preserved*.

I extended you sample a bit to print a single, a double, and a triple space

```
table.addCell(new Phrase("SINGLE SPACED", new Font(BaseFont.createFont(), 36)));
table.addCell(new Phrase("DOUBLE  SPACED", new Font(BaseFont.createFont(), 36)));
table.addCell(new Phrase("TRIPLE   SPACED", new Font(BaseFont.createFont(), 36)));
```

and furthermore updated the used classes to current iText 5.5.x variants.

If you look into the generated PDF internal instructions, you'll see

```
(SINGLE SPACED) Tj
...
(DOUBLE  SPACED) Tj
...
(TRIPLE   SPACED) Tj
```

Thus, iText does literally preserve the spaces.

The visual result:

[image: Screenshot]

As you see the gap is growing and growing. Thus, double and triple spaces are preserved in the visual representation of the PDF!

---

On the other hand, if you copy and paste using Adobe Reader, you get:

```
SINGLE SPACED
DOUBLE SPACED
TRIPLE SPACED
```

Thus, the current Adobe Reader does *not* copy&paste the space characters as they are inside the PDF but collapses multiple ones to a single one.

So:

> Is this a .PDF limitation

This neither is a PDF limitation nor an iText limitation, it is a quirk of Adobe Reader (and some other PDF viewers, too).